# How to rotate 3D object in OpenGL using touch event?

Tags: iphone, opengl-es

I am new to OpenGL programming on iphone, please help me

Comment: This is a very poorly phrased question. Do you understand OpenGL and matrix rotations? Or are you having difficulty with touch events on the iphone? Or both? What have you tried so far? What did/didn't work? Etc.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where to start openGL ES to create and rotate a cube in an iPhone?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2857463/where-to-start-opengl-es-to-create-and-rotate-a-cube-in-an-iphone)

Comment: See also [How do I rotate an object using OpenGL ES 2.0?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3339114/how-do-i-rotate-an-object-using-opengl-es-2-0) and [Where can I find an iPhone OpenGL ES Example that responds to touch?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1039481/where-can-i-find-an-iphone-opengl-es-example-that-responds-to-touch)

Comment: There is an implementation of this in Apple's CoreMotionTeaPot from WWDC ’10 Sample Code http://connect.apple.com/cgi-bin/WebObjects/MemberSite.woa/wa/getSoftware?code=y&source=x&bundleID=20645

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a goog beginning tutorial for OpenGL on the iPhone/iPad:

http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/getting-started-with-opengl-es-for-the-iphone

Comment: +1 And another often quoted resource seems to be this one: http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2009/05/opengl-es-from-ground-up-table-of.html